# Multiple column update

Tags: oracle

I have to execute the following lines of update in a procedure. Can I update this in a single line. Only one table present here.

```
    UPDATE magic_table SET first_col=0,last_col=my_value where first_col is not null;
    UPDATE magic_table SET second_col=0,last_col=my_value where second_col is not null;
    UPDATE magic_table SET third_col=null,last_col=my_value where third_col is not null;
```

If so will it give us any performance improvements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update magig_table
    set first_col  = nvl2(first_col , 0, first_col ),
        second_col = nvl2(second_col, 0, second_col),
        third_col  = nvl2(third_col , 0, third_col ),
        last_col   = my_value
  where first_col    is not null or
        second_col   is not null or
        third_col    is not null;
```

Comment: `third_col  = nvl2(third_col , null, third_col ),` is valid right? if I update the third line like `UPDATE magic_table SET third_col=null,last_col=my_value where third_col is not null;` ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update magig_table
set first_col = case when first_col is not null then 0 end,
    second_col = case when second_col is not null then 0 end,
    third_col = null,
    last_col = my_value
where coalesce(first_col,second_col,third_col) is not null;
```

This way is more performant then usage of `nvl2`. Third column will anyway be null, so there is no need to check it.

Comment: 1 `or` is extra in your answer. Also can you tell me if I update the third line to `UPDATE magic_table SET third_col=null,last_col=my_value where third_col is not null;`

Comment: updated the answer; it is rewritten, first time I was getting your question wrong

Comment: But showing error at the line `where coalesce.. ` `inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER`. Even though `first_col` is varchar.